# Pass String to argument of Syscall in Go

Tags: c, windows, go, dll, type-conversion

I would like to use a C function compiled into a DLL.
Here is the C function that I would like to use:

```
int setProxy(const proxy_config* p_proxy);
```

It takes a const pointer to a C structure defined like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *host_address; 
    int port;           
    char *username;     
    char *password;     
} proxy_config;
```

To do so,
I transformed this C_structure into a Go equivalent as follows:

```
type proxy_configuration struct {
    host_address *uint16 
    port int             
    username *uint16     
    password *uint16     
}
```

To convert the strings, I use the following function:

```
func StringToCString(s string) (*uint16, error) {
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == 0 {
            return nil, errors.New("Problem with the string : "+s)
        }
    }
    p := utf16.Encode([]rune(s + "\x00"))

    return &p[0], nil
}
```

Then I call it:

```
import (
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func SetProxy(host_address string, port int, username string, password string) error {

    [...Conversion code from Go string to Struct...]

    var nargs uintptr = 1
    ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(
        uintptr(setProxy), 
        nargs,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&proxy)), 
        0,
        0,
    )
}
```

where `setProxy` is the result of `syscall.GetProcAddress(DLL,"setProxy")`

The problem is that, when I have a look at the logs generated by the DLL, all the `*uint16` contains only one character and not the whole string whereas port contains the good information.

Thus, my question is:

How can I pass the whole strings in the parameters of `Syscall` and not just the first character?

---

**EDIT**

If I change `return &p[0], nil` in the `StringToCString` by `return &p[i], nil`
I obtain the i-th character of the string... So the problem is definely there, I just do know how to fix it...

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I am also stuck at same point.

Comment: Hello, Unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 3):

> Pass String to argument of Syscall in Go
>
> How can I pass the whole strings in the parameters of [Windows] Syscall?

---

An obvious answer is to look at the Go standard libraries, which make many Windows syscalls.

---

> [package windows](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows?tab=doc)
>
> ```
> golang.org/x/sys/windows
> ```
>
> [func UTF16FromString](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows?tab=doc#UTF16FromString)
>
> ```
> func UTF16FromString(s string) ([]uint16, error)
> ```
>
> UTF16FromString returns the UTF-16 encoding of the UTF-8 string s,
>   with a terminating NUL added. If s contains a NUL byte at any
>   location, it returns (nil, syscall.EINVAL).
>
> [func UTF16PtrFromString](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows?tab=doc#UTF16PtrFromString)
>
> ```
> func UTF16PtrFromString(s string) (*uint16, error)
> ```
>
> UTF16PtrFromString returns pointer to the UTF-16 encoding of the UTF-8
>   string s, with a terminating NUL added. If s contains a NUL byte at
>   any location, it returns (nil, syscall.EINVAL).
>
> [func UTF16ToString](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows?tab=doc#UTF16ToString)
>
> ```
> func UTF16ToString(s []uint16) string
> ```
>
> UTF16ToString returns the UTF-8 encoding of the UTF-16 sequence s,
>   with a terminating NUL removed.

Comment: I did try these functions. But it does not change the result. For me, it looks like something is wrong with my way of passing a structure... The conversion from String to UTF16 and UTF16 to String has been tested. So no problem on this part... :/