# How to execute shell script inside go file?

Tags: shell, go

I want to run a shell script (around 75 lines) in a golang file.

The go file has nothing to do except executing the shell script (It has to be a go file :) )

the code I'm running is this :
the go file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
//    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out:= Native()
    fmt.Println(out)
}
func Native() string {
    cmd, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "./file.sh").Output()

    if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error %s", err)
    }
 
    output := string(cmd)
    return output
}
```

I run it using `go run myfile.go http://example.com`.

It starts executing, but stops and I see this error message:

```
Please specify a target.
                                                                             
Usage:
  ./file.sh http://domain.tld/                                              
  cat urls.txt | ./file.sh
```

Which is what the script prints if I don't give a URL, though I did. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the bash script expects that you provide AN ARGUMENT to it. Which your code clearly doesn't. Thus the shell script prints its help message and exits. In other words: you need to PASS the argument that you gave to GO also to the bash invocation!

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60267359/pass-string-to-argument-of-syscall-in-go

Comment: And note: when the answer given solves your problem, then dont hesitate to accept it (that check mark icon close to the vote count of the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message originates in the called shell script. You are passing the argument `http://example.com` only to your Go program, but not further to the shell script.

Change this code

```
func Native() string {
    cmd, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "./file.sh").Output()

    if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error %s", err)
    }
 
    output := string(cmd)
    return output
}
```

to

```
func Native(target string) string {
    cmd, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "./file.sh", target).Output()

    if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error %s", err)
    }
 
    output := string(cmd)
    return output
}
```

Change the actual call to

```
out:= Native(os.Args[1])
```

You have to import "os" again.

Keep in mind that no checking of the arguments is done here. When no argument is passed in, the program will panic with `index out of range`.

Comment: Okay, I did make all the changes you said! but now nothing is executed! 
when I run " go run myfile.go http ://example.com" 
nothing happens!

Comment: okay, thank you so much for your help.
but I do understand the bash script! I thought it is something related to go (since I'm new to the language). 
I will look into the bash script again to see if I miss anything. :)

Comment: There was a missing "}" which I believe it was deleted by mistake. 
It worked fine with me before, that's why I thought it's the go file!   
But I do understand the bash script sir! :) 
Thank you again.

Comment: @Nadeen You are welcome. Yes, it is KEY to always dissect problems. Before you use tool X *through* another tool Y, make sure that X works exactly as you think it should!